# Formato condicional de spreadsheet de google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un problema con la generación de Formatos Condicionales mediante scripts.
Apartir de un spreadsheet, genero nuevas sheets ("sesion" y "dist.sesion") ademas de copiar otra sheet de otro spreadsheet.

En estas hojas que creo mediante script, tambien creo formatos condicionales mediante una funcion en la que a partir de unos parametros me crea unos formatos u otros:

```
function formatCondicional(f,rang,grup) {

  var cap = rang; 
  
  var conditionalFormatRules = f.getConditionalFormatRules();
  
  f.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = f.getConditionalFormatRules();
  
  switch(grup){
    case "Ubicacions":
      var Planta1='#FF0000';
      var Planta2='#0000FF';
      var Dreta='#C9DAF8';
      var Esquerra='#FFF2CC';
      var EOI='#B7E1CD';
      
      conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, 

  // ****** PLANTA BAIXA ********** DRETA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!PlBaixa");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Dreta");'+ cap + ')>0)')
          .setBackground(Dreta)
          .setFontColor(null)
          .build(),

  // ****** PLANTA BAIXA ********** ESQUERRA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!PlBaixa");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Esquerra");' + cap + ' )>0 )')
          .setBackground(Esquerra)
          .setFontColor(null)
          .build(),

  // ****** PRIMERA PLANTA ********** EOI
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta1");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!EOI");' + cap + ')>0)')
          .setFontColor(Planta1)
          .setBackground(EOI)
          .build(),

  // ****** PRIMERA PLANTA ********** DRETA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta1");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Dreta");' + cap + ')>0)')
          .setBackground(Dreta)
          .setFontColor(Planta1)
          .build(),

  // ****** PRIMERA PLANTA ********** ESQUERRA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta1");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Esquerra");' + cap + ' )>0 )')
          .setBackground(Esquerra)
          .setFontColor(Planta1)
          .build(),

  // ****** PRIMERA PLANTA ********** EOI
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta1");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!EOI");' + cap + ')>0)')
          .setFontColor(Planta1)
          .setBackground(EOI)
          .build(),
   
  // ****** SEGONA PLANTA ********** DRETA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta2");' + cap + ')> 0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Dreta");' + cap + ')> 0)')
          .setBackground(Dreta)
          .setFontColor(Planta2)
          .build(),

  // ****** SEGONA PLANTA ********** ESQUERRA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta2");' + cap + ')> 0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Esquerra");' + cap + ')>0)')
          .setBackground(Esquerra)
          .setFontColor(Planta2)
          .build(),

  // ****** SEGONA PLANTA ********** EOI
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=AND(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Planta2");' + cap + ')>0; COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!EOI");' + cap + ')>0)')
          .setFontColor(Planta2)
          .setBackground(EOI)
          .build()
      );
      break;

    case "Participacions":
      var CapAula='#FFFF00';
      var Comissió='#0000FF';
      var ExOral='#FFBB00';
      var Indicencies='#00AA00';
      var Logistic='#00FF00';
      var NoParticipa='#FF0000';
      var Suport='#EEDD77';
      conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1,
      
  // ****** CAP D'AULA
        SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
          .setRanges([f.getRange(rang)])
          .whenFormulaSatisfied('=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Auxiliar!Participacio");' + cap + ')>0')
          .setBackground('#B7E1CD')
          //.setFontColor(null)
          .build()
      );
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
  f.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
}
```

El problema consiste en que el case "Ubicacions" los ejecuta sin problemas en la hoja de calculo se crea el formato condicional y lo aplica correctamente.
La curiosidad es que el case "Participacions" no crea el formato condicional. Debugueando, veo que el formato condicional se crea (o crea algo en "ConditonalFormatRules") pero cuando finaliza la ejecucion de todo el script, en la hoja, el formato no se ha creado, y portanto no lo aplica. Tampoco me da ningun mensaje de error para poder investigar a partir del error. Simplemente el formato condicional no se incorpora a la hoja.

He revisado el codigo en diversas ocasiones y he intentado poner formulas de condicion más sencillas pero el resultado es el mismo.
Seguramente sea un tema de sintaxis pero he sido incapaz de verlo.

¿Alguien puede echarme un cable?
Gracias y perdonad por la parrafada.

Answer (score 0):

Probando más cosas, me he dado cuenta que al crear los formatos con rango de esta manera, el ultimo formato condicional de cada case no se incorpora al conjunto de reglas de formato.
En el primer case parecia que funcionaba correctamente porque son muchas condiciones a aplicar sobre una lista muy larga de valores posibles. Casualidades de la visda no los probe con los ultimos valores que activaban la ultima condicion. Al probarlo no ha funcionado.
En el segundo case no funcionaba porque estaba probando con una única condición de formato condicional.

De todas maneras me parace algo estraño este problema. Si alguien me puede aportar alguna informacion sobre como trabajar con los formatos condicionales con script, estaré muy agradecido.
Saludos